# PayPal Advanced hosted page inconsistency

Tags: paypal

I am integrating Payflow Advanced into our site and am testing in Sandbox.  I have a page with a Pay Now button.  I have all the necessary accounts, hosted pages, etc. and I successfully get secure tokens  I have tried two ways of accessing my hosted page with these tokens:

1) the Pay Now button opens another HTML page in which my hosted page is specified as the source of an iframe as in

```
    <p>This is a test of hosted pages</p>
    <iframe src="https://payflowlink.paypal.com?SECURETOKEN=73nQZctvqskKbJooHoBr9DQlB&SECURETOKENID=DTesting5991376569967&MODE=TEST& BILLTOSTREET=33 Ames Road&BILLTOCITY=Groton&BILLTOSTATE=MA&BILLTOZIP=01451&BILLTOPHONE=408-110-7975" name="test_iframe" scrolling="no" width="700px" height="700px"></iframe>
```

When this page opens, my hosted page is in the iframe and all info is correct.  After a couple of seconds, something in the PayPal code redirects the browser to the full hosted page.  Everything is correct on this full page as well.

2) In this method I bypass the intermediate HTML page and use an HTML form to access PayFlow directly.  The form has the ACTION set to the exact same string as the src in method 1 and a button to submit the form.  as in

```
    <form id='payment' action="https://payflowlink.paypal.com?SECURETOKEN=73nQZctvqskKbJooHoBr9DQlB&    SECURETOKENID=DTesting5991376569967&MODE=TEST&BILLTOSTREET=33 Ames Road&BILLTOCITY=Groton&BILLTOSTATE=MA&BILLTOZIP=01451&BILLTOPHONE=408-110-7975">
    <input display="inline" type='button' id='paypalbutton' value="Pay with Credit Card or PayPal" class='buttons' onClick="buttonclick('ccpay');">
    </form>
```

When the form is submitted  an invalid merchant message is displayed and no hosted page is displayed.

I don't care which method I use if it would only work correctly.  In method 1, how do I avoid the redirection?
In Method 2, why am I getting the invalid merchant error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `method="POST"` in your `<form>` tag.  This causes your browser to default to using the GET method to submit the form.  This, in turn, causes the browser to strip off all the query parameters from the URL, resulting in an empty request.

So, the solution to this would be to add `method="POST"` to your `<form>` tag.